# JavaScript Function, Passing Parameter Outside of Function

Tags: javascript

In reviewing the following article: https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/

They show the following example:

```
var number = getUrlVars()["x"];
```

Can someone please explain the syntax where the parameter is outside of the function?

Comment: `getUrlVars()` returns an object, of which `"x"` is a property. It's the equivalent of doing `MyObject["x"]`, or `MyObject.x`.

Comment: It isn't a parameter.  It's an array or object accessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was written as the following would you have asked the question?

```
var myVariables = getUrlVars()
var number = myVariables["x"];
```

The function call `getUrlVars` is returning an object `{x: 123}` and the developer is reading a property of the object right away. Instead of writing it in two steps, they wrote it as one.

Doing it that way is great if you are only reading one property from the object, but if you want to read more than one, it would be better to write it out by storing `getUrlVars()`  into a variable and than using that to read the properties. That way you are not executing `getUrlVars` more than once.

Answer (score 1):

1. `var num = getUrlVars()["x"];` This expression is used when the called function is returning a object and you want to get only desired value out of the returned object. Here `["x"]` is not a parameter it used as object property accessor.

```js
function getUrlVars(){
  return{
    'x': 'This is x',
    'y': 'This is y'
  }
}

var num = getUrlVars()["x"];

console.log(num)
```

2. `var number = getUrlVars('["x"]');` In this expression you're passing `[x]` as parameter to a function.